# change text inside a included php-file

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a HTML/PHP page where I retrieve a data from a database.
Using PHP includes I have med a head.php and footer.php. And inside my index.php I include this to files at the start and at the end. 
But now I came across a problem, because depending on the information retrieved from the database in index.php (or any other file) I want to change the `<h1></h1>` of the page, but that part is in head.php.

What is the simplest way to change the text inside `<h1>` in an already included .php-file?
EDIT: Is it possible with PHP? Can I use HTML, or do I have to use javascript?

**head.php**

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
//A lot of code that makes the frame of my page
<h1 id="pagetitle"></h1>
//more code that makes the frame of my page
```

**index.php**

```
include 'head.php';

//..retrieve information from database
//..change text inside <h1> inside head.php


include 'footer.php';
```

**footer.php**

```
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show, how your head looks like. Insert a variable probably even with short tags style `<?=$var;?>` Try / fail / repeat until success :)

Comment: may be you have to give a class or id for that h1 then you make a function to trigger the onload event of the document to change the text of that h1 according to it's id or class as you set

Comment: @Osama: But it is not every time I need to change the `<h1>`, but sometimes. So when I dont need to change it, it can be empty.

Comment: @cssBlaster21895: I have now added a example of my head.php and footer.php

Comment: no you have to support this function with a conditional if statement to change case when true else do nothing

Comment: I don't see place where you retrieve something from the database. This should be before head. And later some var should be assigned and used inside h1. `<h1><?=$var;?></h1>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once PHP has parsed and included the contents of your header code, it's a done deal.  PHP isn't going to re-parse it later.  You'd need some JS or JQuery to go back and replace the value in the code, say, replace by ID.

For example (JS inside of index.php):

```
document.getElementById("pagetitle").innerHTML = "<?php echo $myTitleVariable ;  ?>";
```